# Joining the different infotypes of SAP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sap-hr

I am quite unexperienced with SAP. I received an XML file with different infotypes from SAP (like PA0000, PA0001,...). I want to load this data into a database, using a datawarehouse model.

In that case, one table of this database (for example Person) exists of data from multiple infotypes. My question here is if there is a list or model of recommended 'joins' between all these infotypes?

This because I want to know if I need to do a INNER, LEFT or OUTER JOIN between infotypes PA0002 and PA0105 for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official "model" for this, but most of the time the most common infotypes have a commonly used cardinality (for exemple IT 0021, "Family" is most of the time "3" : several possible, overlapping) .

if you want to be really sure, look at table T582A in your SAP HR system . The field ZEITB contains the occurence for a given infotype : for one person, the following values are possible :

- 1  Record must have no gaps, no overlappings
- 2  Record may include gaps, no overlappings
- 3  Record may include gaps, can exist more than once
- A  Infotype exists just once from Jan.1 1800 to Dec.12 9999
- B  IT exists for maximum of once from Jan.1 1800 to Dec.12 9999
- T  Time constraint is based on subtype or subtype table
- Z  Time constraint for time management infotypes -> T554Y